# window.print() : page is printed with lot of empty pages

Tags: angular, canvas, ng2-charts

I have a canvas chart in my html page with other data's which will print roughly 9 pages, but it is printing 638 pages with 629 empty pages.

I'm using ng2-charts in my angular application.

If canvas was removed I have only 9 pages as seen in the below image
[image: If canvas was removed]

If canvas was added I have only 638 pages as seen in the below image
[image: If canvas was added]

my canvas code in HTML is

```
<div class="chart">
    <canvas id="mycanvas" class="canvas" baseChart width="200" height="200"
        [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels" [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [colors]="lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType"
        [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
    </canvas>
    <div id="existing-image-id" class="chart-img"></div>
</div>
```

my angular code for canvas options is

```
this.lineChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
            text: "Argus 3 Year Historical Rating Trend",
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontColor: '#4D4E50',
        },
        animation: {
            onComplete: function () {
                function convertCanvasToImage() {
                    let canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
                    let image = new Image();
                    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
                    return image;
                }
                if (index === 0) {
                    let pnGImage = convertCanvasToImage();
                    document.getElementById('existing-image-id').appendChild(pnGImage);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hard to say.. If you tried to remove the chart to test? You can use ngx-print library to test it, too

Comment: @Flo already I'm using ngx-print

Comment: To play around with it you can make a little Stacklblitz example? Otherwise try to set the canvas color to blue maybe and show is it on every "blank" page.